# composite foreign key mapping hibernate entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have three tables in MySQL database.
1. Table users with primary key: username.
2. Table orders with primary key: orderid and foreign key: username (refer to username from Table users)
3. Table ordersdetail with primary key: id and composite foreign key: orderid; username (refer to orderid and username in orders.)

Now how to setup Entity class OrderDetail for Table ordersDetail to let hibernate work appropriately.

// Order Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {

@Id
private long orderid;
private double price;   
private String status;  
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="username")
private User user;

//Constructor take 0 args and 4 args.
public Order() {
    this.user = new User();
}

public Order(long orderid, double price, String status, User user) {
    this.orderid = orderid;
    this.price = price;
    this.status = status;
    this.user = user;
}


@Embeddable
class CompositeKey implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8711530222180590954L;

public String username;
public long orderid;

}
```

//OrderDetail Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordersdetail")
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3936223721422733989L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private int quantity;
private Order order;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "goodsid")
private Goods goods;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "orderid", referencedColumnName = "orderid") })
private CompositeKey key;

public CompositeKey getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(CompositeKey key) {
    this.key = key;
}
```

Comment: You should not have a composite key. Orderdetail should have foreign key to order(id) only.